# getDateTimeInstance(): Different Behavior for Different Locale

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, sapui5, cldr

I am doing date format using this function

```js
// DateFormat required from "sap/ui/core/format/DateFormat"
DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({ pattern: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm" });
```

The format is working fine in "DE" but it is returning wrong value in "EN".
In both languages, the time is 24 hour. What I need is:

- In English, the time text should contain AM or PM.
- In German, the time text should be in the 24h format.

How can this be achieved?

Target UI5 version: 1.108

Comment: Does the date have to be formatted strictly in this "yyyy-MM-dd" pattern? Why not format the date locale-dependent as well (E.g. "16.04.2022" in Germany but "Nov 16, 2022" in the US)?

Comment: Why should "English" show as am/pm? 24hr is much more acceptable these days, in the UK at least.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Unicode's Date Field Symbol table](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table):

- `HH` corresponds to the "24-hour-cycle format"
- `hh` corresponds to the "12-hour-cycle format"
- **`jj` "is the only way to [...] request a locale's preferred time cycle type (12-hour or 24-hour)."**

If not required otherwise, I'd strongly discourage from hardcoding the `pattern` in the format options in order to **let the framework format the date and time depending on the user locale.** You can **use the `format` option instead** to specify which symbol to incorporate (e.g. `jj` instead of `hh` or `HH`) when formatting the date time value.

Run this snippet to see the result:

```js
globalThis.onUI5Init = () => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/format/DateFormat",
  "sap/ui/core/Locale",
  "sap/ui/core/Configuration",
  "sap/m/VBox",
  "sap/m/ObjectStatus",
], (DateFormat, Locale, Configuration, VBox, ObjectStatus) => {
  "use strict";
  const currentUserLocale = Configuration.getLanguageTag();
  const control = new VBox({
    items: [
      new ObjectStatus({
        title: "Locale \"de-DE\"",
        text: DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
          format: "yMdjjmm",
          UTC: true,
        }, new Locale("de-DE"))
          .format(new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(23, 0)))
      }),
      new ObjectStatus({
        title: "Locale \"en-US\"",
        text: DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
          format: "yMdjjmm",
          UTC: true,
        }, new Locale("en-US"))
          .format(new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(23, 0)))
      }),
      new ObjectStatus({
        title: `Your Preferred Locale ("${currentUserLocale}")`, // Detected locale as per https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/91f21f176f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070
        text: DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance({
          format: "yMdjjmm",
          UTC: true,
        }).format(new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(23, 0)))
      })
    ],
    renderType: "Bare",
  });

  control.addStyleClass("sapUiTinyMargin").placeAt("content");
});
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m,sap.ui.layout,sap.ui.unified"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-oninit="onUI5Init"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

Given today at 23:00:00Z:

> Locale "de-DE": 28.4.2023, 23:00
> Locale "en-US": 4/28/2023, 11:00 PM

API reference: [`sap/ui/core/format/DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat#methods/sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance)

---

Same can be achieved in property binding within XML declaratively via `type` and `formatOptions`.

```xml
<SomeControl xmlns="..."
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  core:require="{ DateTimeOffset: 'sap/ui/model/odata/type/DateTimeOffset' }"
  someControlProperty="{
    path: 'myODataModel>...',
    type: 'DateTimeOffset',
    formatOptions: {
      format: 'yMdjjmm'
    },
    ...
  }"
/>
```

API reference: [`sap/ui/model/odata/type/DateTimeOffset`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTimeOffset)
Documentation (must-read): [Dates, Times, Timestamps, and Time Zones](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/6c9e61dc157a40c19460660ece8368bc)
Documentation: [Formatting, Parsing, and Validating Data — Data Binding](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/07e4b920f5734fd78fdaa236f26236d8) (in XML)